# Unix cp command destination = . (dot)?

Tags: unix, command-line, copy, command

What does `.` (dot) mean as the destination of the `cp` command?

For example:

```
cp ~dir1/dir2/dir3/executableFile.x .
```

When this executes it copies the file successfully with the correct file name, but I'm wondering is this what a destination of '.' will always do or is there another purpose?

Within the reference material I've seen, dots are used in front of files to indicate 'hidden', but in that has no relation to the command above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dot represents the current directory
while dotdot is the parent directory.

Comment: in case you didn't know, that tilde '~' represents your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

As EvilTeach's answer says, `.` is the current directory, and `..` is the parent directory.

There are basically two ways to use the `cp` command:

```
cp file1 file2
```

will copy `file1` to `file2`, creating `file2` if it doesn't exist or (depending on permissions) possibly clobbering it if it does.

The other way is:

```
cp file1 file2 ... dir
```

where `dir` is an existing directory.  With this form, you can specify one or more files, and they'll *all* be copied into the specified directory `dir` *with their existing names*.

(This can be a pitfall sometimes; `cp foo bar` behaves very differently depending on whether there's an existing directory named `bar`.)

As you mention, files (including directories) whose names start with `.` are *hidden*. What this means is that (a) the `ls` command won't list them (unless you use the `-a` or `-A` option), and (b) a shell wildcard such as `*` or `*.txt` will omit them.  (GUI directory managers such as Nautilus may also omit them, depending on your settings.)

This applies to the current directory `.` and the parent directory `..`.  `ls` won't include the `.` and `..` entries in its output; `ls -a` will.